# How do draw a polygon using gdimage in C?

Tags: c, drawing

I've got an assignment at Uni which involves drawing lots of different shapes, all of whihch has to be drawn using the gdImage library in C language. So far I've used `gdImageLine` and `gdImageRectangle`, like this:

```
gdImageLine ( gdImage, 150, 70, 170, 90, blue);
```

or

```
gdImageRectangle( gdImage, 110, 80, 160, 120, blue);
```

I'm very inexperienced/have no clue about C, so any help would be great!

Hi, sorry I got confused. I wanted to draw a shape using "gdImagePolygon" in the way/similar to how I used the other two, if that makes sense? I've been given this link (http://cnfolio.com/public/libgd_drawing_reference.html), thanks

Comment: I cannot really understand what do you want to ask. Failed to call the function? Or the function didn't draw as expectation? Or something else?

Comment: You're asking how to draw a polygon, but you said that you did draw a rectangle. A rectangle *is* a polygon. So... could you be more explicit on what you're having issues with?

Comment: Hi, sorry I got confused. I wanted to draw a shape using "gdImagePolygon" in the way/similar to how I used the other two, if that makes sense? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`gdImagePolygon`](http://www.boutell.com/gd/manual2.0.33.html#gdImagePolygon) has the following signature:

```
gdImagePolygon(gdImagePtr im, gdPointPtr points, int pointsTotal, int color)
```

`gdImagePtr` is a pointer to a [gdImage Structure](http://www.boutell.com/gd/manual2.0.33.html#gdImage)

`gdPointPtr` is a pointer to a [gdPoint structure](http://www.boutell.com/gd/manual2.0.33.html#gdPoint) (just two `ints`, x and y of the point):

```
typedef struct {
    int x, y;
} gdPoint, *gdPointPtr;
```

`pointsTotal` is the number of points you'll have total (minimum of 3)

`color` is the color

The sample to draw a triangle:

```
... inside a function ...
gdImagePtr im;
int black;
int white;
/* Points of polygon */
gdPoint points[3];           // an array of gdPoint structures is used here
im = gdImageCreate(100, 100);
/* Background color (first allocated) */
black = gdImageColorAllocate(im, 0, 0, 0);  
/* Allocate the color white (red, green and 
  blue all maximum). */
white = gdImageColorAllocate(im, 255, 255, 255);  
/* Draw a triangle. */
points[0].x = 50;
points[0].y = 0;
points[1].x = 99;
points[1].y = 99;
points[2].x = 0;
points[2].y = 99;
gdImagePolygon(im, points, 3, white);
/* ... Do something with the image, such as 
  saving it to a file... */
/* Destroy it */
gdImageDestroy(im);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code snippet from scratch, please notice me if there is any mistake. Thanks.

```
int Draw_Polygon (int Side, ...)
{
    va_list Ap;
    va_start (Ap, Side);
    int X_1 = va_arg (Ap, int);
    int X_0 = X_1;
    int Y_1 = va_arg (Ap, int);
    int Y_0 = Y_1;
    int Cnt;
    for (Cnt = 0; Cnt < Side-1; Cnt++)
    {
        int X_2 = va_arg (Ap, int);
        int Y_2 = va_arg (Ap, int);
        gdImageLine ( gdImage, X_1, Y_1, X_2, Y_2, blue);
        X_1 = X_2;
        Y_1 = Y_2;
    }
    gdImageLine ( gdImage, X_1, Y_1, X_0, Y_0, blue);
    va_end(Ap);
    return 0;
}

int main (void)
{
    if (Draw_Polygon (5, 0, 0, 0, 10, 12, 12, 16, 8, 5, 0) == 0) // Draw a pentagon.
    {
         // Success !
    }

    if (Draw_Polygon (6, 0, 0, 0, 10, 12, 12, 16, 8, 6, 3, 5, 0) == 0) // Draw a hexagon.
    {
         // Success !
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Quick pseudocode to draw a polygon of `N` sides, with a side length of `L`:

```
Procedure DrawPol (integer N,L)
  Integer i
  For i=1 To N
    Draw (L)
    Turn (360/N)
  EndFor
EndProcedure
```

This pseudocode is base on two primitives, which are common in languages like LOGO:

- `Draw (L)` : draws a line of `L` pixels in the current direction
- `Turn (A)` : changes current direction by adding `A` degrees to the
  current direction

To implement `Draw` and `Turn` using the `Line` function you can use something like this:

```
Real CurrentAngle = 0  /* global variable */
Integer CurrentX = MAXX / 2  /* last point drawn */ 
Integer CurrentY = MAXY / 2  /* initialized to the center of the paint area */

Procedure Draw (Integer L)
  Integer FinalX,FinalY
  FinalX = CurrentX + L*cos(CurrentAngle)
  FinalY = CurrentY + L*sin(CurrentAngle)
  Line (CurrentX, CurrentY, FinalX, FinalY)  /* gdImageLine() function actually */
  CurrentX = FinalX
  CurrentY = FinalY
EndProcedure

Procedure Turn (Float A)
  CurrentAngle = CurrentAngle + A
  If (CurrentAngle>360)              /* MOD operator usually works */
    CurrentAngle = 360-CurrentAngle  /* only for integers */ 
  EndIf
EndProcedure
```

Comment: *so any help would be great!* That's what I've done: provide some help. Read the comment close to `Line (CurrentX...)`